How modern runtimes handle both interpreted and JITted code at the same time?
I have a personal project, I want to write a JIT compiler/runtime in Rust (well, the language is not that relevant). I'm thinking about using a technique where the code is interpreted first and then JITted only when the runtime decides it is time to JIT (whatever that means).
This imposes a certain problem. How exactly interpreted and JITted code interacts with each other? Here's what I understand so far:
An interpreted function would look like this:
fn handle_call(context: &mut Context) {
    let current_fn = context.current_fn();
    for instr in current_fn.instructions() {
         match instr {
             // do something
         }
    }
}

so in Rust I have a single function, that is called with different context, depending on what the interpreted function we are running at the moment.
It is easy to imagine that if I find a CALL instruction, then I retrieve the corresponding data, create new Context object and make (recursive) call to handle_call function.
But how do I call a JITted function? And how will a JITted function call interpreted function? Here are two options I can see:

JITted functions follow the same signature, they accept &mut Context objects. This makes things very simple, since now calls between all functions are just calls through pointers. But I don't like this solution, since this involves potentially big overhead of building, passing around and using Context objects. For example if our function accepts an i32, then it can be passed in registers. What is worse ARGS have to be packed into Context object, and since we don't know how many of them there will be, this can mean a potential heap allocation per call. And this is a huge overhead.

All functions, JITted or not, are treated the same way as low level, machine code functions. So JITted code simply emits instructions corresponding to some calling convention. While interpreted code now has to transform recursive call to handle_call into an appropriate machine code call. But how do I do that? I don't know the signature at compile time (as in: compiler's compile time), so how can I generate an arbitrary call? The only thing I can think of is to generate machine code on the fly when CALL instruction is seen.
On the other hand how do I call interpreted function from JITted one? I cannot use a single handle_call to handle all calls. Now I need to generate a wrapper for each function in my language that does the opposite to what I've mentioned earlier: it takes arguments passed through some low level calling convention, packs them into Context object and then calls handle_call with it.
I'm not worried about performance of this process, after all it is JITted code that is supposed to be optimized, not the interpreted code. What I'm worried is that this already requires JITting of at least some code. Originally I though that I can separate interpretter from JITter, but with this approach I have to use JITter at least partially. Which is a significant complication. Not only complication, I thought that I can use interpreter on platforms where I don't have JITter implemented. With this approach I cannot.


So am I forced to sacrifice performance here? Or JIT (at least partially) from the beginning and sacrifice simplicity and modularity? How do tiered JITters like Java (see here and here) do that? What am I missing here?

I am not a real expert on this, but AFAIK the .Net runtime does not interpret any function. It first compiles anything to byte code (IL), and at runtime, compiles the byte code to machine code "just in time" - which means before the function is called the first time. See C# JIT compiling and .NET on Stackoverflow.

... let me add I found this blog post The .NET IL Interpreter, which talks about a non-production ready IL interpreter implementation somewhere deep in the .Net Core. Maybe it helps.

@DocBrown Hmm, that might be true for .Net (I removed it from my question). But I think that Java does have an interpreter, this is at least what this: https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-tiered-compilation and this article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/java/how-tiered-compilation-works-in-openjdk/ suggest.

It seems you already wrote an answer on Stackoverflow which covers the topic to some degree.

@DocBrown yeah, it doesn't really cover the issue I have here though. Distinguishing between compiled and not-compiled functions doesn't help much. I still need to generate appropriate calls if I want them to be optimized. The main issue is that I want to avoid using JITter when in interpreted mode.

You can make this slightly less complicated by imposing the requirement that JIT code cannot call non-JIT code, except through function-as-variable (closures, C#'s delegates, etc)

I don't know how it is solved in the Java runtime, but my guess would be that when the JIT compiles a function, it also provides an "interpreter-friendly" adapter as a second entry point. In the other direction, for each interpreted function called from a compiled function, the JIT may provide a "compiled-code" friendly adapter as well, which gets replaced as soon as the interpreted function gets compiled.  But when crossing the border between interpreted and compiled code, I would always expect some marshalling overhead.

@pjc50: we already took C#/.Net out of the equation (see former comments), so lets focus on Java.  "JIT code calling non-JIT" would only simplify things when there are no exceptions allowed, but as soon as we want those exceptions to work (like higher order functions/callbacks/closures ...), I see no reason why JIT code could not call interpreted code in any kind of situation.

@DocBrown because then JITted code needs to keep around two sets of call instructions, depending on whether it calls a jitted function or not. And a branch instruction. We are talking about micro optimization here, but I thought that I can avoid that.

@freakish: yes, that's what I guess what's needed. It will allow you to keep the interpreter separate from the JIT compiler, but not the other way round (but I guess the latter is not your goal).

@DocBrown too many comments, I missed one of your previous. Yes, marshalling overhead is expected and not a problem. My goal is to have JITted code optimized only. I didn't think about JITted code providing another entrypoint of itself for the interpreter. Actually that sounds very reasonable, and I might actually do that. I need to think more about that, but feel free to write it down as an actual answer.

Again, some braindead close voting and downvoting, I bet it came from one of our usual suspects, probably because there are literally two questions asked here inside of one. Sorry, but this is a well researched and focussed question. I just hope some more people here balance these senseless, destructive votes.

"Hmm, that might be true for .Net (I removed it from my question). But I think that Java does have an interpreter" The description given by DocBrown aligns perfectly with how standard Java works. When people talk about Java being interpreted, they mean it interprets the bytecode.  CPython also has a similar design with the distinction that the byte code is generated by the runtime if it doesn't already exist.

Perhaps this is useful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/ (note: that's old) you might find more current references here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode

@JimmyJames of course they mean it interprets the bytecode. That's exactly how I use the term here. What DocBrown says is that C# always JITs a function, it doesn't have the interpretation step.

@freakish 'It first compiles anything to byte code (IL), and at runtime, compiles the byte code to machine code "just in time"' That's a pretty precise description of what Java does. That's how Java has worked since before C# was a thing.

@freakish You realize that Java code is compiled as a separate step from running, right? https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html

Java HAS a bytecode interpreter.

If you do some searching on Hotspot you should find some good information. Partly because it's 20th century tech, there's a lot of information about how it works.  I remember some old conference talk about all the various optimizations it does.  One thing to note is that it doesn't just JIT on load, it will recompile and optimize during application execution as well.

@JimmyJames people in this thread are trying to convey, that C# does not use an IL interpreter and is different from Java in that aspect.

@Basilevs IL meaning 'inline'? What with respect to Java are you referring to exactly?

@Basilevs Or which part is different?

@JimmyJames CIL is intermediate language in .NET, mostly same stuff as bytecode in Java. Aspect - is interpreter used or not. .NET does not interpret, Java does.

@JimmyJames who and where exactly claimed that Java is not interpreted first and compiled next? That's literally what I've been saying all the time, from the beginning. The point is that Java interprets the code at runtime first, unlike C#/.Net as far as I understand, which JITs the bytecode right from the beginning. It doesn't matter that the compiler produces bytecode first, it is not the topic here.

@freakish Why do you think that? I've pointed you to several references that explain that is not how it works (at least not vanilla Java.)  The JVM executes bytecodes (class files). The Java compiler compiles Java source files (java files) into bytecodes.

@JimmyJames I don't think you understand the words that are being said/written here. That's fine, thank you.

@freakish If you are saying that Java source is interpreted by the JVM, that's wrong.

@JimmyJames where did I say "source is interprted"? Where did I even mention Java's source code?

@freakish C# source is compiled into bytecode which is executed by the runtime, right?  Java source is compiled into bytecode which is executed by the runtime.  What about that is different?  What is it that you are referring to that is 'interpreted' here?

@JimmyJames as I said: you don't understand the topic. It is different, read everything we wrote agian, read linked articles. Thanks.

@freakish If you can't explain what you mean, I think you are the one who doesn't understand.  The only think a vanilla JVM 'interprets' is Java bytecode.  Are you saying that .NET doesn't do that?

@freakish It also JITs all the bytecode it executes. If you think it's interpreting bytecode without machine compilation, that's wrong.

@JimmyJames we've literally said that like 10 times that .Net does not interpret the bytecode, but JITs it straight away. It is not me who has problems with understanding.

@freakish 'Modern' Java also does that too which I keep trying to tell you.  There is/was a 'client' VM that did interpret bytcodes but it's not recommended for use because there's no benefit. I'm not sure it's even still an option in current releases.

@JimmyJames both articles that I've linked earlier (from this and previous year) claim the opposite about Java. It does not JIT right from the beginning. And none of the references you provided support what you just said.

@JimmyJames: You wrote "C# source is compiled into bytecode which is executed by the runtime" - when you mean "the bytecode is JIT - compiled into machine code which is then executed", that's correct. For Java, the source code is compiled into bytecode, too, but the bytecode isn't necessarily JIT-compiled. I did not know this beforehand, please check the links given by the OP in the 3rd comment under this question, I took the freedom to add them to the question.

@DocBrown It was my understanding that non-JIT execution was something that was phased out a long time ago and that JVMs now aggressively and preemptively compile (and recompile) bytecode to machine code. I concede that I may be mistaken to the degree. The first link refers to Java 7 which is very old (8 was released in 2014) I don't know anything about the author for the second one, but it is more recent.  It's possible that the capability is still used but even if it is, I don't think it has much impact. I think there's a good reason that .NET didn't bother with that feature.

@freakish I seem to be mistaken about the removal of interpreted execution. I assure you I understand the distinction, however.  I came across this article about a contemporary Java JIT runtime which might be of interest to you.  If seems to contains details specifically about your question: "In fact a JIT-compiler just needs to be able to accept JVM bytecode and produce machine code - you give it a byte[] in and you want a byte[] back."

I don't know how it is solved in the Java environment, but here is an idea for an approach which might work for you.
When the JIT compiler compiles a function, it could provide two entry points:

one standard entry point for other compiled code - so compiled functions can call other compiled functions without overhead
an "interpreter-friendly" adapter as a second entry point, which provides the unmarshaling of arguments from the context and then calls the first entry point.

In the other direction, for each (potentially) interpreted function called from a compiled function, the JIT may provide an adapter for the compiled code which does the specific marshaling. That adapter can be replaced as soon as the interpreted function gets compiled. For the latter, the JIT has to do some book-keeping where it has placed such adapter calls in the JIT-compiled version, and it needs a mechanic to modify such adapter calls later, or simply recompile the specific functions again.
When crossing the border between interpreted and compiled code, in either direction, I would always expect some marshalling overhead, I think that's unavoidable. Still, what I wrote above lets you develop the interpreter independently from a JIT compiler (just not the other way round).

FYI, while this answers my question, it introduces another issue: how do I pass around references to functions? As two pointers + flag? Together with atomic check. Eh, doesn't sound too good. And it is a mandatory feature. Maybe JITting everything from start (like C# does) is actually simpler and better.

@freakish: well, I am programming C# since 2003, and  as far as I remember, C# programs had never such startup time issues like early Java. So I guess a bytecode interpreter may be expandable under performance aspects. Still, the link in my second comment under your question gives an different motivation: getting the CLR quickly available on new platforms for which a specific JIT is not (yet) available.

@freakish compiled code may be given a native wrapped over interpreted function, until the latter is compiled.

@Basilevs consider what happens when A takes reference to C and passes it to B, so that B calls it. B doesn't know whether this ptr is compiled or not. And so I need to pass more information, and runtime check. Unless I JIT everything from the beginning with some standard calling convention.

If I go down the interpreter + JITter road, then I think that glueing interpreter with some assembly is unavoidable unfortunately. It seems that Java has interpreter per architecture, I read it somewhere. That would explain a lot...

For example: JavaScript in Safari is run a fe times in the interpreter to avoid expensive translation. If a loop or a function is run a dozen times then it is compiler producing unoptimised code with very fast compile time. After 100 repeats it is compiled again with a much better but slower compiler. Then after 1000 or so executions it runs Clang to produce the fastest possible code.
Now let’s say you have a variable that could in principle have any type but it was int in 990 of 1000 cases. So the clang compiler will produce code like “if type is Int then run totally optimised code for the int case else run code compiled with the lightweight compiler”.
Every time the system decides to update the compiled code it stops execution, compiles, then replaces the old code either the new code. To avoid pauses the compilation can be done con a separate thread.

Sure you read the question in full, not just the title?
